# adding header and append incoming string data into csv python

Tags: python, csv, header, append

I received an error message when trying create header and adding incoming data in the next row

```
def copy_real_data(real_curData, real_curTime):       
     real_el_data   = open(temp_path, "a")
     real_prev_data = open(temp_path, "r").read()

     header = ["Reading Right Shoulder Pitch Data", "ReadingTime"]

     if real_prev_data =='':
        real_el_data.write(header)
        real_el_data.write(','.join([real_curData, real_curTime]))
        real_el_data.write('\n')
        real_el_data.close()
```

calling from outside:

```
  simulation.copy_real_data(str(0.76575), str(565657.989))
```

it works previously.. but after do it several times.. it generates an error message:

```
 real_el_data.write(header)
 TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple file write would always expect a `character buffer`.

It works for you when the if condition is not hit.

You can try the following(using `csv` module):-

```
import csv
def copy_real_data(real_curData, real_curTime):       
     real_el_data   = open(temp_path, "a")
     real_prev_data = open(temp_path, "r").read()

     header = ["Reading Right Shoulder Pitch Data", "ReadingTime"]
     csvwriter = csv.writer(real_el_data) 

     if real_prev_data =='':
        csvwriter.writerow(header)

     csvwriter.writerow([real_curData, real_curTime])
     real_el_data.close()
```

Or if you do not want to use csv:-

```
def copy_real_data(real_curData, real_curTime):       
     real_el_data   = open(temp_path, "a")
     real_prev_data = open(temp_path, "r").read()

     header = ["Reading Right Shoulder Pitch Data", "ReadingTime"]

     if real_prev_data =='':
        real_el_data.write(','.join(header))
        real_el_data.write('\n')
     real_el_data.write(','.join([real_curData, real_curTime]))
     real_el_data.write('\n')
     real_el_data.close()
```

I havn't tested the code but it should work.

Comment: thanks. i did the second one and i missed this one : real_el_data.write('\n')  . thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great. But I would recommend using `csv` module when you are workinng with csv. Do give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it. It seems the command:

```
real_el_data.write(header)
```

only takes one argument while  the 'header' contains two arguments.
I modified:

```
if real_prev_data =='':
    with open(temp_path, 'w') as f:
        f_csv = csv.writer(f)
        f_csv.writerow(header)
```

let me know if you notice there is a simpler way to do it

Answer (score 0):

In your code header is a list and write method accept character buffer object(string).Try using write(','.join(header))

Comment: I did this one, but seems needs to put extra line after it: write(','.join(header))   then  .write('\n')